# If function: if column A==1 AND 1 column B is in list X and column C is not null, 1. else, 0

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, attributeerror

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
index  Ind.  Code Code_2
    1     1   NaN      x
    2     0     7    NaN
    3     1     9      z
    4     1   NaN      a
    5     0    11    NaN
    6     1     4    NaN
```

I also created a list to indicate values in the column Code, something like this:

```
Code_List=['7', '9', '11']
```

I would like to create a new column for the indicator that is 1 so long as Ind. = 1, Code is in the above list, and Code 2 is not null

I would like to create a function containing an if statement. I tried this and am not sure if its a syntax issue, but i keep getting attribute errors such as the following:

```
def New_Indicator(x):
    if x['Ind.'] == 1 and (x['Code'].isin[Code_List]) or (x['Code_2'].notnull()):
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0

df['NewIndColumn'] = df.apply(lambda x: New_Indicator(x), axis=1)
```

> ("'`str`' object has no attribute '`isin`'", 'occurred at index 259')
>   ("'`float`' object has no attribute '`notnull`'", 'occurred at index
>   259')

Comment: What is your expceted output?

Comment: Using apply and if is not a good way to process dataframes. It's like running a for loop over a numpy array. You can perform operations that result in logical series on entire columns, and combine them to get the result you want much more cleanly

Comment: Basically, `pandas.DataFrame.apply` method with `axis=1`, passes rows in a loop to the assigned function in which case its `New_Indicator`. The thing is when x is a row, `x['Ind.']` is not a series and rather it is the value of "Ind." column for that row, so for other columns. You should not use `pandas.Series` within your apply method.

Comment: Also, the way you're doing it, you can pass New_Indicator directly. No need to wrap in lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your function, `x['Code']` is a string, not a Series. I suggest you use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
ind1 = df['Ind.'].eq(1)

codes = df.Code.isin(code_list)

code2NotNull = df.Code_2.notnull()

mask = ind1 & codes & code2NotNull

df['indicator'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   index  Ind.  Code Code_2  indicator
0      1     1   NaN      x          0
1      2     0   7.0    NaN          0
2      3     1   9.0      z          1
3      4     1   NaN      a          0
4      5     0  11.0    NaN          0
5      6     1   4.0    NaN          0
```

**Update** (as suggested by @splash58):

```
df['indicator'] = mask.astype(int)
```

Comment: `df['indicator'] = mask.astype(int)`